# Export to CSV and format in a table

Tags: 2013, powershell, csv

I am using this code but I would like to view in a table and export as a CSV but all my attempts have failed.  Where does the code go?

```
$siteUrl = "URL" 
$site = Get-SPSite $siteUrl
$site.RootWeb.SiteAdministrators
$groups = $site.RootWeb.sitegroups
foreach ($grp in $groups) {"Group: " + $grp.name; foreach ($user in $grp.users) {"  User: " + $user.name} }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about trying this?

```
SPGroupCollection $groups = $site.SiteGroups;
```

instead of

```
$groups = $site.RootWeb.sitegroups
```